# jquery скрипт из 3.1.1 не работает в 3.3.1. В чем проблема?

Tags: jquery

Есть скрипт что идеально работал во всех версиях вплоть до 3.1.1 включительно. 
На сайте обновили версию jquery до 3.3.1 и скрипт перестал работать. Помогите плиз. Буду благодарен за наводку.

```
$(".ul-dropfree").find("li:has(ul)").prepend('<div class="drop"></div>');
$(".ul-dropfree div.drop").click(function() {
  if ($(this).nextAll("ul").css('display') == 'none') {
$(this).nextAll("ul").slideDown(400);
$(this).css({
  'background-position': "-11px 0"
});
  } else {
$(this).nextAll("ul").slideUp(400);
$(this).css({
  'background-position': "0 0"
});
}
});
$(".ul-dropfree").find("ul").slideUp(400).parents("li").children("div.drop").css({
  'background-position': "0 0"
});
```

Полная версия скрипта с html частью [тут](https://jsfiddle.net/malefikus13/hfpmm3a8/)

UPD: Так, я кажется понял...это благодаря роскомнадзору...у меня провайдер блочит ip гугла...приехали. Прошу прощения за беспокойство господа. отбой.

Comment: В JSFiddle на JQuery 3.3.1 работает. Следовательно - дело не в версии JQuery. Лог(что выдаёт консоль) в студию.

Comment: Как сказано выше , на JSFiddle все работает, какая ошибка?

Comment: хм, у меня на нескольких компах на этой версии не работает. но в консоли только вот это: 
GET https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.js 0 ()
(index):120 Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined
    at window.onload ((index):120)

Comment: Похоже не определяет $. Такое может быть только если неверно подключил jQuery. Покажи где подключаешь скрипт , и как:)

Comment: так как обычно <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script> в <head>

Comment: Полностью весь Head, не уверен но что то может перекрывать его.. Сейчас напишу ответ

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Скорее всего у тебя jQuery подключен позже чем сам скрипт.

```
<script src='https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js'></script>   
<script src="myscripts.js"></script>
```

Посмотри не наоборот ли у тебя.

Comment: именно так и подключаю. я понять не могу, почему у меня и у всех где я включаю jsfidle по ссылке, скрипт не работает. Не раскрывается по клику дерево. А у всех выше срабатывает корректно...

Comment: Хм.. Давай подумаем почему.. Может как бы это глупо не звучало стоит сбросить настройки браузера? или вовсе переустановить его?  Знаю глупо звучит но если такая ситуация странная.

Comment: Так, я кажется понял...это благодаря роскомнадзору...у меня провайдер блочит ip гугла...приехали. Прошу прощения за беспокойство.

Comment: Так вот оно что, тогда просто смените ссылку на эту: https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-3.3.1.min.js

Comment: да, я просто скачал через прокси библиотеку и подключил ее со своего хостинга. Спасибо большое.

Comment: Обращайся, а если честно jQuery уже начинает устаревать на фоне Anuglar, React, Vue. Советую посмотреть в их сторону они сейчас намного больше востребованы:)